# How to create multiple windows using "command + n" in non document based application

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is there a way to create/enable having multiple windows using "command + n" in a non document based application? I want to have unlimited instance of that window (not actually unlimited, but might be 6-7 instances) using command + n

Or I have to create a document based app and port all my code in new project template is the only solution?

I can see the menu button for "New" is disabled right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways to do this.
First connect the New menu item to an IBAction method. 
Name the method whatever makes sense to you.

Next, you will want to add some kind of property to your controller ( app delegate for simplicity ) that is basically a window stack only storing a reference to each window or window controller. NSMutableArray should do nicely.

Now you can do the next part a few ways, but I would recommend creating an NSWindowController subclass with a nib/xib (especially if these windows will have the same basic things in them).
Do what you want in the nib file.

Now in your IBAction method, create a new instance of your window controller class, add it to your mutable array. Tell it to load its window.

You only have to decide if the controller should be removed from the stack and set to nil if its window is closed. 
Many ways to handle that, and up to your design to know what is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
NSWindowController *yourWindow=[[[[yourWindowController alloc]init]retain]autorelease];
[yourWindow loadWindow];
```

Comment: How would I 1) create unlimited number of windows using this? 2) how to attach this code to work with command + n

I have already tried this to create a new window but not unlimited

Comment: Badsically iniside yourWindowController class implement this -(NSString*)windowNibName

Comment: I wrote this code in AppDelegate.m file and tried to connect it from "New" menu button, but I am not able to connect it from there. So I put this code in one of my viewcontroller and attach it with a button it was working there..

Comment: don't you think creating new app windows using "command + n" should be by default available?